# Let $f$ be a function from a metric space to a metric space. Prove that $f$ is continuous i.f.f it sends convergent sequences into convergent seq.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta

My question is as stated in the title; ***Let $f$ be a function from a metric space to a [second] metric space. Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if it sends convergent sequences into convergent sequences*.**

To be honest, I am a bit stuck on this one and would appreciate any input how to get started. What is the intuition?

Comment: The intuition is that a continuous function sends points that are close to each other in the domain to points that still remain close to each other. Write down the definition of continuity, you should be able to prove it just by writing down the definition. For example, if $f$ is continuous at $a$, take a sequence $\{a_n\}$ that approaches $a$ and see what happens to $f(a_n)$'s.

Comment: I think I got that part of the proof, i.e $x_i \rightarrow x \Rightarrow f(x_i)\rightarrow f(x)$ if $f$ is continuous. It's the other way around that gets me baffled, I think one need some kind of transitive proof or similar...

Comment: Yeah. You should use a contrapositive proof. Both directions follow from the definition of continuity really.

Comment: Okey, that helped me out A LOT. Thank you. You'll have my **solved** very soon

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Take your time and write a good solution. You can even post your solution as an answer to your own question and I'll upvote it if it's correct. You'll get the self-learner badge then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $\{a_n\}$ be any convergent sequence in $X$ and suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, i.e. $\forall \delta>0$, $\exists M > 0$ such that

$$n\geq M \implies |a_n-a| < \delta$$

Now because $f: X \to Y$ is continuous at $x=a$, for any $\epsilon>0$ you will find a positive $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$. How can you combine these two facts?

To prove the other direction, suppose that $f$ is not continuous at some point $x=a$, then $\exists\epsilon_{\star}>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, we have $|x-a|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(a)| \geq \epsilon_{\star}$. Take $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ to construct a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n\to a$. 
Now define a new sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that

$$b_n=\begin{cases}
a_n & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ a & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=a$ still remains true but $f(b_n)$ is NOT a Cauchy sequence because $|f(b_{2n+1})-f(b_{2n})|=|f(a_{2n+1})-f(a)| \geq \epsilon_{\star}$. Because any convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence, the sequence $\{f(b_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge. Contradiction.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not an answer to the  question. It is only given that $f(x_n)$ converges to some limit whenever $(x_n)$ converges. You cannot assume that $x_n \to a$ implies $f(x_n) \to f(a)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I agree with your criticism overall but I cannot immediately see where I have assumed that. Could you be more precise please? I'll fix it then.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please see the edit. I have constructed a new sequence $\{b_n\}$ that converges to $a$ but $f(b_n)$ is not Cauchy and hence it cannot be convergent. Let me know if you still see a problem.

Comment: The edited answer is right and I have given an upvote.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your constructive criticism. You pointed out a point that I had totally missed.